# Проблема интеграции AdMob в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, admob

Проблема в том, что в версии ассета AdMob 5.4.0 и раньше при инициализации рекламы в коде нужно было передавать строку з AppID. ТеперЬ, в версии 6.0.0 нужно это делать как-то по другому, никак не могу понять что делать.
Вот строка кода с инициализацией:
`MobileAds.Initialize(appID);`
Вот ошибка:
`Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Action<GoogleMobileAds.Api.InitializationStatus>'`

Comment: Перед тем, как задавать подобные вопросы, потрудитесь хотя бы [документацию](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/quick-start) официальную посмотреть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты пытаешься пропихнуть string туда, где ожидается Action на результат инициализации. [Тут подробное описание того как что делать.](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/quick-start)